# Responsive Tailwind class not applying to MUI component

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, tailwind-css

I wan't my button to have upper margin only on mobile:

```
import { Button } from '@mui/material';

<Button
  type="submit"
  variant="contained"
  color="primary"   
  className="w-full md:w-auto sm:mt-4"
>
  Submit
</Button>
```

`md:mt-4` doesn't work and neither does `sm:mt-4`. They don't apply to the MUI `<Box />` either.

```
//not working
<Box className="md:mt-4">
 //...
</Box>
```

Are MUI styles overriding Tailwind's?

Answer (score 0):

The way Tailwind works, you have to define a default class for mobile devices and an override for larger screens (mobile-first approach).

So in your case, you should aim to set your classes like this `mt-4 sm:mt-0`

That would tell Tailwind to use margin-top-4 for all sizes from 0px until 640px (sm screen size), where margin-top-0 would kick off.

If you want to be more generous and override it on screens of 768px upwards, you can use the `md` utility, like this: `mt-4 md:mt-0`.

Hope it's clear, and hopefully it resolves your issue :)

Comment: Doesn't do the job

Comment: I suspect your tailwind classes are not building.

If you can check the built css file, e.g public/css, search for "mt-4". If you don't see it there, then Tailwind is certainly not scanning all your template files. You'd have to update your `tailwind.config.js` in that case. Let me know if this is possibly the underlying problem.